# Difference between "glass" and "shot"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I heard this line in a song:

> It wasn't a shot of cognac, it was a glass of cognac.

Then the crowd listening to the singer started laughing.

What is the difference in meaning between these two words in this context? Maybe I don't get it because I am a little far from the culture of drinking.

[Here](http://open.spotify.com/track/5WA3hoBC6vUsNZMPw2V1Rk) is the spotify link to the song, unfortunately that's a live version and I couldn't find it on YouTube. He sings that between 4:18 and 4:20.

Comment: A shot is a small measure, usually 25-50ml. A glass could be anything up to a litre. Haven't heard the song though, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me (I get "This content is not available" but I don't have a spotify account, so that maybe the reason?). If you put your mouse over the 'downvote' arrow you can see a short 'reason', but I agree with you that an uncommented down vote is of little use to the person who posed the question. (wasn't me)

Comment: I'll try to find a working link, thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shot is significantly smaller than a glass and one usually drinks very strong liquor in a shot glass. Thus when the artist says that it wasn't a shot of cognac, but a glass, he is remarking on how much strong liquor was being drunk.

Comment: That's assuming an indefinite article has been omitted by OP (or before). If one assumes one has been inserted: _It wasn't a shot cognac; it was a glass cognac_ it's in the same ballpark of 'It's not sippin' whusky; it's gulpin' whusky'.

Answer (score 1):

**Shot**:

*a small amount of,  especially a jigger,  of liquore*

**Shot glass**:

*a shot glass is a small glass designed to hold or measure spirits or liquor, which is either drunk straight from the glass ("a shot") or poured into a cocktail.*

Source: Wiki

In your line, the person, who probably ordered a shot of cognac, seem to complain that he/ she was given  a *glass* (a larger quantity) compared to a *shot*